# С помощью какого заголовка сервер возвращает браузеру jpg и png?

Tags: c++, http, веб-сервер

Я пишу небольшой http сервер,так как кроме html текста ничего возвращать еще не прихоидлось в качестве заголовка я отсылал просто "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n", что нужно добавить, что браузер читал картинки ?

Comment: `Content-Type` соответствующий отправляемым данным

Comment: пробовал "Content-Type: image/png\n\n" и "apng" приклеить к "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n", не помогает. Почему то начинается скачивание этого файла на устройство, с которого был сдлеан запрос.

Comment: Как приклеивали-то?

Comment: простая конкатинация, которую позволяет сделать класс стринг, с помощью перегруженного +

Comment: Не такая уж и простая, раз не помогло. Какая конкретно конкатенация-то?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с устройством протокола HTTP... Вон например там должно быть не `\n\n`, а `\r\n`. И не храните бинарные данные в string

Comment: склеивание строк с помощью перегруженоого в библиотеке <string> оператора +

Comment: А как лучше хранить бинарные данные ?

Comment: Конкретный код склеивания является государственной тайной и вы его нам ни в коем случае не покажете?

Comment: класс стринг реализован в стандартной библиотеке с++

Comment: Стандартная библиотека не срабатывает сама по себе, её должен запускать кто-то другой, например ваш код. А вы свой код показывать не хотите и непонятно что как у вас вообще работает

Comment: void HTTP_handler::GET_request(){
    std::string MSGbuffer, head;
    head = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n";
    MSGbuffer = head + "Content-Type: image/png\n\n";
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("/home/anton/Загрузки/Сайт/content/step2.png");
    while(!fin.eof()){
     std::string temp;
     std::getline(fin, temp);
     MSGbuffer = MSGbuffer + temp;
    }
    fin.close();
    send(client_d, MSGbuffer.c_str(), MSGbuffer.length(), 0);
}

Comment: @DenverToha, под вопросом есть кнопочка [edit].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: <размер файла в байтах>

{данные}
```

И для jpeg'а `Content-Type: image/jpeg` соответственно.

Comment: @gbg, а стартовая строка в заголовке http разве чувствительна к регистру?